# Correct algebra manipulation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is this correct to do?

$$ -\frac{1}{\beta} \ln (\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{\beta} \ln (\frac{1}{2})^{-1} = \frac{1}{\ln(1/2)} = \frac{1}{1} \times \ln\frac{2}{1} = \frac{1}{\beta} \ln2 $$

Comment: $-\ln(x)=\ln(1/x)\neq \ln(x)^{-1}$

Comment: oh thought that was the case. oaky thank you

Comment: @Surb : $\ln(1/x) = \ln \Big( (x)^{-1} \Big)$ and $\ln(1/x) \ne \Big( \ln (x) \Big)^{-1}.$ But which meaning was intended? Maybe that's made clear by the next step, but you should have made it clear in your comment which one was intended.

Comment: @MichaelHardy ... Well it seems that OP understood what I meant which was my purpose. Anyway, your comment as well as the accepted answer are now shading light on the possible confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-\frac 1{\beta} \ln \left( \frac 1 2 \right) = \frac 1{\beta} \ln \left[ \left( \frac 1 2 \right)^ {-1} \right] = \frac 1{\beta} \ln 2$